# How to connect ONVIF IP camera in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, networking, ip-camera, onvif

I was creating an application for ONVIF IP cameras I successfully scan and found an IP camera from the network but I can't get **Device information** and **Media Profiles**

- I Get This Error

> ```
> Devices errorMessage:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
>                                                                                          <html><head>
>                                                                                          <title>404 Not Found</title>
>                                                                                          </head><body>
>                                                                                          <h1>Not Found</h1>
>                                                                                          <p>The requested URL requested was not found on this server.</p>
>                                                                                          </body></html>
> ```

- Here Code

  ```
       fun getDevices() {
       var onvifManager = OnvifManager()
       onvifManager.setOnvifResponseListener(this)
       val manager = DiscoveryManager()
       manager.discoveryTimeout = 10000
       manager.discover(object : DiscoveryListener {
           override fun onDiscoveryStarted() {
               println("Discovery started")
               Log.e("jfsfnfskdjf", "Discovery startede")
           }

           override fun onDevicesFound(devices: List<Device?>) {

               for (device in devices) if (device != null) {
                   System.out.println("Devices found: " + device.hostName)
                   Log.e("jfsfnfskdjf", "Devices found:" + device.hostName)
               }
           }
       })


       val onvifDevice =
           OnvifDevice("192.168.0.117")
       onvifDevice.username = "admin"
       onvifDevice.password = ""

       onvifManager.getDeviceInformation(
           onvifDevice
       ) { device, deviceInformation ->

           if (device!= null) {
               println("Device found: " + deviceInformation.model)
               Log.e("jfsfnfskdjf", "deviceInformation found:$deviceInformation.model" )
               Log.e("jfsfnfskdjf", "deviceInformation found:${deviceInformation.manufacturer}" )
           }

       }
  ```

Does anyone have to idea how to solve this? I want to connect the IP camera using my application and show live and configure